# Update app from netcore 2 to 3 can't use automapper

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I updated my app to net core 3 and when I run application I get error
concerning Automapper (at least i mean)

I have update relative library running dotnet -outdate an then updating the dependencies

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.MoneyResolver Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.MoneyResolver': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.MoneyResolver'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.TimeSpanResolver Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.TimeSpanResolver': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.TimeSpanResolver'.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

Seems a dependency injection error but cant understand

Comment: Why is your resolver accepting a string in its constructor? That means it needs a string dependency.

Comment: public class DefaultResolver: IValueResolver<DataRow, object, object>
    {
        private readonly string memberName;
        public DefaultResolver(string memberName)
        {
            this.memberName = memberName;
        }
        public object Resolve(DataRow source, object destination, object destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return source[memberName];
        }
    }

Comment: Obviously :)  `Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyDemo.Models.Mapping.Resolvers.DefaultResolver'`

Comment: so what i should do :(

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: Could you suggest what you mean...please

Answer (score 0):

For your `DefaultResolver`, it has constructor which needs to pass the `string memberName`.

In general, there are three ways for AutoMapper a custom value resolver to use

- MapFrom
- MapFrom(typeof(CustomValueResolver))
- MapFrom(aValueResolverInstance)

For [Custom constructor methods](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#custom-constructor-methods), you need to try the third option like:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Total,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(new CustomResolver())
    ));
```